# iOS compiling gives codesigning error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, build

I am trying to build my application and I get the following:

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

My configuration is set as "debug" and in my project properties, on the build tab, I have a profile selected under the code signing identity. And in parenthesis in light gray text says "currently matches 'iPhone Developer..."

But, if I click "build and run," even though I get the error, the application still runs on my device.

Why am I getting this warning? Ideas? It is a brand new profile that I just created and stuck in XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a 'build and clean'.  That often solves my problems with code signing errors.